# Breakdown List Into Multiple Lists (C#, Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My first Stack Question so let me know if I need to revise anything.

**Update**

Thanks to Mithgroth's help, I was able to read up on group by and figure out how to put non bulk and bulk items on their own truck:

```
private IEnumerable<string> AddItems(IEnumerable<DispatchItemViewModel> items, string dispatchId, string userId, bool forRigWalk)
    {
        int Ordinal = 1;

        var isBulk = from item in items
        group item by item.Product.IsBulk == true into newGroup
        select newGroup;

        foreach (var bulk in isBulk){
                var newTruck = new DispatchTruckViewModel
                {
                    Ordinal = Ordinal++,
                    Items = bulk.ToList()
                };
                AddItems(new List<DispatchTruckViewModel> { newTruck }, dispatchId, userId, forRigWalk);
            
        };
      return bulk;
   }
```

HOWEVER I still need each bulk product on their own truck. Here is the current outcome vs the desired outcome:

Current Outcome based on current code: [image: Current Outcome]

Desired Outcome:

[image: Desired Outcome]

**Original Post**
Our system takes in a list of products, then auto creates a truck dispatch to take those products to where they need to go. Some of these products are bulk and need their own truck. So I want to be able to iterate through the list and create a new truck for each bulk product that has only that one bulk product in it. Then I want all non bulk products to get put on a truck together.

The current result:
[current list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2V4W.png)

Desired Outcome: [desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbJdT.jpg)

My current code does create a new truck for each bulk product however I can not get it to disperse the products the correct way, it simple creates multiple trucks and add all the products to every truck

```
private IEnumerable<string> AddItems(IEnumerable<DispatchItemViewModel> items, string dispatchId, string userId, bool forRigWalk)
    {

        foreach (var bulk in items){

            if(bulk.Product.IsBulk == true){
                var item = bulk.Product;
                var newTruck = new DispatchTruckViewModel{
                    Ordinal =+ 2,
                    Items = items.ToList()
                };
                 AddItems(new List<DispatchTruckViewModel> { newTruck }, dispatchId, userId, forRigWalk);

            }
        };
        var singleTruck = new DispatchTruckViewModel{
            Ordinal = 1,
            Items = items.ToList(),
        };

        return AddItems(new List<DispatchTruckViewModel>{singleTruck}, dispatchId, userId, forRigWalk);
    }
```

To show my work, I also tried this here but I am running into a type issue:
error message: [type issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17vPB.png)

```
{
  
        foreach (var bulk in items){

            if(bulk.Product.IsBulk == true){
                var item = bulk.Product;
                var newTruck = new DispatchTruckViewModel{
                    Ordinal =+ 2,
                    Items = (ICollection<DispatchItemViewModel>)bulk
                };
                 AddItems(new List<DispatchTruckViewModel> { newTruck }, dispatchId, userId, forRigWalk);

            }
        };
        var singleTruck = new DispatchTruckViewModel{
            Ordinal = 1,
            Items = items.ToList(),
        };

        return AddItems(new List<DispatchTruckViewModel>{singleTruck}, dispatchId, userId, forRigWalk);
    }
```

Here is where the add items function goes:

```
 private IEnumerable<string> AddItems(IEnumerable<DispatchTruckViewModel> Trucks, string dispatchId, string userId, bool forRigWalk)
    {
        var retList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var truck in Trucks)
        {
            var dTruck = new DispatchTruck{
                Id = _idService.GetIdString(),
                CreateUserId = userId,
                DispatchId = dispatchId,
                Ordinal = truck.Ordinal,
                EstimatedArrival = truck.EstimatedArrival == null || truck.EstimatedArrival == "" ? null : (DateTime?)(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
                .AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64(truck.EstimatedArrival))),
                TenantId = TenantId,
                UpdateUserId = userId,
                DriverName = truck.DriverName,
                SwamperName = truck.SwamperName,
            };
            if (forRigWalk)
            {
                dTruck.Status = ServiceConstants.DELIVERED_STATUS;
            }

            _dispatchTruckRepo.Add(dTruck);
            foreach (var item in truck.Items)
            {
                if (item.ProductId == "" && item.Product != null) {
                    item.ProductId = _productService.AddForInventory(item.Product, item.Product.Categorys.First().Id, userId);
                    retList.Add(item.ProductId);
                }
                var dItem = new DispatchItem{
                    Id = _idService.GetIdString(),
                    DispatchTruckId = dTruck.Id,
                    ExpenseId = item.ExpenseId == "" ? null : item.ExpenseId,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId == "" ? null : item.ProductId,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity,
                    Price = item.Price,
                    TenantId = TenantId,
                };
                _dispatchItemRepo.Add(dItem);
            }
        }
        return retList;
    }
```

Comment: This line `Items = items.ToList()` will create a new list and add the items of `items` to that list. It's just a copy. You need to filter that list per truck.

Comment: What does the `AddItems` do to return an `IEnumerable<string>` You screenshots show more like a table.

Comment: Yeah good question, I'll add the add items function where we set the dispatch into the db. Also good tip, I am trying to add a where query but im still getting a type issue.

Comment: Isn't `group by` what you are trying to achieve? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: @Mithgroth close! but what I want is to add a new truck for every bulk product that is selected. So what I am more wondering is if I use a group by syntax, and there are two products that are bulk, how do I put each product on its own truck instead of both products on the same truck.